# Is a norm of a vector a constant to a summation?

Tags: summation, vectors

I have a simple question:

if we have $$\sum_{\textbf{x}}\|\textbf{x}\|^2\, p(\textbf{x}),$$ can I treat the norm as a constant and remove it from the summation?

Comment: No: it depends on the index of summation. (Unless, of course, you know that the vectors over which you’re summing all have the same norm.)

Comment: Yes, you do need to specify what set of $\bf x$ you are summing over.